# Change Google Map Marker Inset iOS

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps

Is it possible to move the google map marker a bit to a certain side? It has no `padding` and no `inset` to adjust.

Sample `GMSMarker`, with custom `iconView`:

```
lazy var marker_User: GMSMarker = {
    let marker = GMSMarker(position: defaultlLocationCoordinate)
    marker.iconView = UserMarker().loadView()
    marker.map = self.mapView
    return marker
}()
```

I'd like to make the center move the left side by a few points. To give more context, see the screenshot:

[image]

So if you make this design, and apply it as `iconView` of your marker, then the true coordinates of your marker would be pointing at the center of this whole custom view (including label and house image), instead of making the house imageView as the center of the coordinate.

I'm thinking, one solution for this is to adjust the inset, offset, padding of this marker.

In moving the Google logo of 
`map.padding = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 190.0, right: 0)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the record, I was able to pull it off, using the `GMSMarker`'s `groundAnchor`.

**GroundAnchor**:

> The ground anchor specifies the point in the icon image that is
>   anchored to the marker's position  * on the Earth's surface. This
>   point is specified within the continuous space [0.0, 1.0] x [0.0,  *
>   1.0], where (0,0) is the top-left corner of the image, and (1,1) is the bottom-right corner.  *  * If the image has non-zero
>   alignmentRectInsets, the top-left and bottom-right mentioned above  *
>   refer to the inset section of the image.

Although if someone could explain this in much simpler way, that would be helpful. What I did was I put two textFields and a button at the center of my map and put random values (e.g. 0.1, 0.5, etc...) to set the specific marker's `groundAnchor`, then voila, I got the appropriate values.